# View.OnClickListener() in Android responding for the wrong button

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am having an issue registering a call when a button is clicked.

I have 2 EditTexts, one Button and one CheckBox. I would like to get the onClick() function called when the Button is pressed. Unfortunately, it only happens when the CheckBox is pressed, but it's not the correct ID so I am confused.

Here is the java code:

```
Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectToServer);
connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ....
}
```

As you can see, I look for the id "connectToServer".

This is my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffb6b6b6"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:padding="2px" android:text="Settings" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="13px">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="25px"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:text="Set server settings" />

        <TableLayout android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:stretchColumns="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="IP address:" />

                <EditText android:id="@+id/serverIP" android:maxLength="15" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_marginTop="4px" android:text="Port:" />
                <EditText android:id="@+id/serverPort" android:maxLength="15" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">
            <Button android:text="Connect" android:id="@+id/connectToServer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffb6b6b6"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:padding="2px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px" android:text="Availability" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="13px">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="25px"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:text="Set device available" />

        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Uncheck to disallow anyone from\nremotely connecting to the device." />
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox" android:gravity="right"
                    android:checked="true" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The important line I believe would be this:

```
<Button android:text="Connect" android:id="@+id/connectToServer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
```

but the code only gets called when the CheckBox button is checked or unchecked. I am not sure why that is.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no event for the checkbox, this is the only event. The checkbox gets checked inside onClick() of the button.

Comment: Then please show the full source what you are trying..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectToServer);


connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

});
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very much, that did solve it! Was the issue using View.OnClickListener()? Should I rather use OnClickListener() from now on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure but I think View.OnClickListener() is provide click listener for all the current View, So use the simple method I suggested, And if you find this is useful for you then please upvote and mark it as a correct so its help you and other user also, Thanks.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot! (I had to wait a few minutes until I could mark it as correct). Thank you very much, you helped me a great deal!

Answer (score 3):

there is much simpler way to handle click events

1) add android:onClick to assign the function like that

```
<Button android:id="@+id/connectToServer"
android:text="Connect" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="onClick_connectToServer"
/>
```

2) implement onClick inside your activity

```
public void onClick_connectToServer(View v) {

        String tag = "" + v.getTag();
// here you can handle the action
}
```

in this case, you don't need to add onClickListener explicitly.

---

*Social Coding @ [AspiroTV](https://github.com/AspiroTV)*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  I changed the button order within XML and the onClickListener started calling the wrong event.  The view looked correct from the device but the View IDs in R.java were incorrect.

Using Eclipse:  I simply did Project->Clean...

The event listeners started working correctly.